# 502 Bad Gateway when using reverse proxy nginx

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I've been trying to set up a reverse proxy with docker and nginx for the past few days with little success. When I run `docker-compose up` and attempt to reach my server via my IP address I do get the appropriate page. However when attempting to curl a domain listed in my `/etc/hosts` file it just returns a `502 Bad Gateway`. My main projects are a series of laravel projects with which I am using the following `docker-compose.yml` files.

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/web.docker           
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        expose:
            - "8080"
        links:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - beanstalk
            - cache
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3307"
            - "DB_HOST=mysql"
            - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
            - "REDIS_HOST=redis"
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.18
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=db"
        ports:
            - "3307:3307"
    redis:
        image: redis:3.0
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    beanstalk:
        image: schickling/beanstalkd
        ports:
            -  "11300:11300"
    cache:
        image: memcached:alpine
        ports:
            - "11211:11211"
```

with the following nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

the `docker-compose.yml` for my proxy is currently:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    build: ./
    networks:
      - project1
      - project2
    ports:
      - 80:80

networks:
  project1:
    external:
      name: projec1_default
  project2:
    external:
      name: project2_default
```

and I also have a nginx conf file in which I define all of the projects in the following manner

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name project1.xxx.tech www.project1.xxx.tech;

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://project1_web_1:8080/;
  }

  access_log off;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

running `docker network ls` shows that the services listed in the docker-container files are running on their assigned ports, one thing that is rather confusing is that the web section of the services show that it is listening on 80 as well as 8080 or 8081, depending on the project. I'm not sure if this is causing a conflict or not.

I have also tried to make use of the nginx-proxy project to similar results. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think `proxy_pass http://project1_web_1:8080/;` should be `proxy_pass http://web:8080/;`, if it is running inside the container

Comment: The container containing that nginx conf file is my reverse proxy, so those two containers are completely separate. I can give it a shot though -- That did not seem to work

Comment: Did the external nginx container launch on the same network created by docker-compose or the default bridge network?

Comment: I did not specify anything when launching the nginx container, however when I stop it with `docker-compose down` it does say that my networks are external, and that the process is skipping those. So I assume that the nginx container has no issue with actually seeing the laravel projects

Comment: Can you post the command you used for launching the external `nginx` container?

Comment: just a simple `docker-compose up -d` with the `docker-compose.yml` that I posted above

Answer (score 0):

So the problem ended up being solved by the use of the [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) project from jwilder

I didn't have to do much more than specify the virtual host and virtual port. I'm not sure why the virtual port had to explicitly be set to 80, but that seemed to resolve the problems. This is my `docker-compose.yml` file for my laravel projects:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/web.docker           
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - app
        environment: 
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=appname.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
        expose:
            - "80"
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - mysql
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3307"
            - "DB_HOST=mysql"
            - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
            - "REDIS_HOST=redis"
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.18
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=db"
        ports:
            - "3307:3307"
```